# C# WriteAttributeString - Multiple Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using System.Xml to create an XML document. I need to create something similar to the following:

```
<Communication primary="N" value="heisenburg@albuquerquecarwash.com" purpose="PERSONAL" type="EMAIL"/>
```

I can use 'WriteAttributeString' to get as far as this:

```
<Communication primary="N"/>
```

The problem is it won't let me add any more attributes and I'm a bit stuck. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: The code is below to create the above XML:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("CommunicationList");

writer.WriteStartElement("Communication");
writer.WriteAttributeString("primary", "N");
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement();
```

I need to add the 'Value', 'Purpose' and 'Type' attributes to this and I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should render what you want:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("CommunicationList");

writer.WriteStartElement("Communication");
writer.WriteAttributeString("primary", "N");
writer.WriteAttributeString("value", "heisenburg@albuquerquecarwash.com");
writer.WriteAttributeString("purpose", "PERSONAL");
writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "EMAIL");
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't bother to try it as I thought it would give me four seperate tags as opposed to concatenating them into one. Thankyou.